# Android & SQLite : Sum column, send to Setter and get the value from another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have method getJumHutang, this method use for SUM all hutang column and save it to class Hutang, class Hutang use for setter and getter.

this is the code for method getJumHutang :

```
public class HutangDAO extends HutangDBDAO  {

    public HutangDAO(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Cursor getJumHutang(Hutang hutang){
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select sum("+DataBaseHelperHutang.JUMLAH+") FROM "+DataBaseHelperHutang.HUTANG_TABLE+"", null);
        try {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                hutang.setJumHutang(cursor.getDouble(0));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
            close();
        }

        return getJumHutang(hutang);
    }
```

this code in MainActivity that call method setJumHutang :

```
package mainmenu;

import pemasukan.PemasukanMainActivity;
import piutang.PiutangActivity;
import hutang.Hutang;
import hutang.HutangDAO;
import hutang.HutangActivity;

import com.androidopentutorials.sqlite.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity   {

    TextView txtHutang;
    TextView txtPiutang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
        txtHutang = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHutang);
        HutangDAO dao = new HutangDAO(this);
        Hutang hutang = new Hutang();
        dao.getJumHutang(hutang);
        txtHutang.setText(hutang.getJumHutang()+"");
    }

    public void callPiutang (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PiutangActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void callHutang (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HutangActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void callPemasukan (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PemasukanMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onShowQuitDialog();
    }

    public void onShowQuitDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Quit?");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }

}
```

and the class Hutang (Setter and Getter) :

```
public class Hutang {

    private double jumhutang;

    public Hutang(){
        super();
    }

    public double getJumHutang(){
        return jumhutang;
    }

    public void setJumHutang(double jumhutang){
        this.jumhutang = jumhutang;
    }
}
```

class HutangDBDAO :

```
package hutang;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class HutangDBDAO {
    protected SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelperHutang dbHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public HutangDBDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        open();
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        if(dbHelper == null)
            dbHelper = DataBaseHelperHutang.getHelper(mContext);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
        database = null;
    }
}
```

and the last is DataBaseHelperHutang :

```
package hutang;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelperHutang extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hutang.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    public static final String HUTANG_TABLE = "hutang";

    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
    public static final String TANGGAL_PINJAM = "pinjam";
    public static final String JUMLAH = "jumlah";
    public static final String TANGGAL_KEMBALI = "kembali";
    public static final String DARI = "dari";
    public static final String KETERANGAN = "keterangan";

    public static final String CREATE_HUTANG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + HUTANG_TABLE + "(" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + TANGGAL_PINJAM + " DATE, " + JUMLAH + " DOUBLE, "
            + TANGGAL_KEMBALI + " DATE ," + DARI + " TEXT,  "
            + KETERANGAN + " TEXT);";

    private static DataBaseHelperHutang instance;

    public static synchronized DataBaseHelperHutang getHelper(Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DataBaseHelperHutang(context);
        return instance;
    }

    private DataBaseHelperHutang(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_HUTANG_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DataBaseHelperHutang.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + HUTANG_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

and i got this error :

```
08-12 13:42:47.721: W/dalvikvm(1504): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a95ba8)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504): Process: com.androidopentutorials.sqlite, PID: 1504
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidopentutorials.sqlite/mainmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at hutang.HutangDAO.getJumHutang(HutangDAO.java:30)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at hutang.HutangDAO.getJumHutang(HutangDAO.java:40)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at mainmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     ... 11 more
```

when i click  08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):   at hutang.HutangDAO.getJumHutang(HutangDAO.java:30) eclipse highlights this line at HutangDAO.class :

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select sum("+DataBaseHelperHutang.JUMLAH+") FROM "+DataBaseHelperHutang.HUTANG_TABLE+"", null);
```

for 08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at hutang.HutangDAO.getJumHutang(HutangDAO.java:40) eclipse highlights this line at HutangDAO.class :

```
return getJumHutang(hutang);
```

and 08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504):     at mainmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)  eclipse highlights this line at MainActivity.class :

```
txtHutang.setText(hutang.getJumHutang()+"");
```

sorry if my question kind like a noob question, but i find myself stuck in this error..

Comment: Looks like your error was `08-12 13:42:47.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1504): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidopentutorials.sqlite/mainmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`. Do you have the code for where you tried to start `ComponentInfo`? Seems like that's where the `NullPointerException` is coming from.

Comment: i already edit my MainActivity, that is all my code in MainActivty class. i actually new in android and not really know where i start ComponentInfo . .

Answer (score 1):

The call `return getJumHutang(hutang);` calls the same function recursively, but because of the `close()`, `database` is now `null`.

That call in line 40 should have been `return hutang.getJumHutang();` instead.
(And I'm not sure if that `close()` belongs there.)

Comment: I was writing the same answer :)

Comment: but when i dont use close() this database will leaked, i will update HutangDBDAO, and Databasehelper

Comment: `getJumHutang()` expects the database to be open. Giving it the responsibility to close it would be strange.

Comment: when i try to delete close() it i got this error : A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.androidopentutorials.sqlite/databases/hutang.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed. so where i should write close() in my app??

Comment: "when it is no longer needed"